# In the world of Mortal Engines, what is the status of Christianity?

Tags: mortal-engines

In the world of the Mortal Engines series by Philip Reeve, I recall two references to Christianity, but they seem to contradict each other:

- In *Fever Crumb*, "Cheesers Crice" is said to be the name of "an obscure cockney god":

  > “Cheesers Crice!” Ted shouted (it was the name of some obscure cockney god) and knocked Charley sprawling in his hurry to get away.
- In *Infernal Devices*, Oenone Zero is revealed to be a Christian, going to a chapel and praying to Jesus Christ, pretty much in the same way that people do today.

What is the actual status of Christianity in this [far-future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/130038/31394) setting? Is it a still-practised religion, or something that's faded from cultural knowledge except as a malapropised name?

(The temporal settings of *Fever Crumb* and *Infernal Devices* are quite far apart from each other as well as from the present day, but that of *Fever Crumb* is earlier, so if Christianity was remembered until Oenone Zero's time, that includes Fever Crumb's time before it.)

Comment: Apparently there are Christian majority Traction cities *She had sent a card at Christmas, because although Theo wasn’t very religious he lived in a Christian city and probably celebrated all their strange old festivals, but all she had written was Happy Xmas and a few lines of news about herself and Dad.* - A Darkling Plain

Comment: @Valorum Did Theo live in a Traction city? I thought he was from a static city in the continent we now call Africa, although it's been many years since I read the books so I may be misremembering.

Comment: I could easily be wrong. I've only grabbed the quote from the Illustrated Guide